# How to config Detox's assembleAndroidTest to ignore submodules?

Tags: android-espresso, e2e-testing, detox

I got some error on adding Detox into an existing Android project, but got lots of errors on the `assembleAndroidTest` command, like

```
./gradlew assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug
```

Some errors :

```sh
> Task :submodules:oomcatcher:mergeDebugAndroidTestNativeLibs FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':submodules:oomcatcher:mergeDebugAndroidTestNativeLibs'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'. If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets, see https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#automatic_packaging_of_prebuilt_dependencies_used_by_cmake
```

However, `assembleDebug` works very well, as:

```
./gradlew assembleDebug -DtestBuildType=debug
```

Since it's a large project, and I don't care the oom-catcher Android Test task, I was wondering if we could config to ignore that errors?